# Import models from different apps to admin Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an admin page for `my project` including `app1` and `app2`

```
myproject
    settings.py
    urls.py
    admin.py
app1
app2
```

In `myproject/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    path('app2/', include('app2.urls')),
    
]
```

In `myproject/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app1.models import User
from app2.models import Manager, Employee, Task, Template


admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Manager)
admin.site.register(Employee)
admin.site.register(Task)
admin.site.register(Template)
```

Why doesn't my admin page import any models at all? Thanks!

Comment: admin.py file is only autogenerated file in app only not in main project root. I think you can't create admin.py file in your main project so that's why it is not importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside each app you must put admin file so can django track these files , so in your app1 in admin.py file related to app1 directory `app1/admin.py` , you need to put this code

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from app1.models import User
 
admin.site.register(User)
```

and in app2 in admin.py related to app2 directory`app2/admin.py`  put this :

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from app2.models import Manager, Employee, Task, Template


admin.site.register(Manager)
admin.site.register(Employee)
admin.site.register(Task)
admin.site.register(Template)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every app should have their own admin.py file by default design. Django will detect it in the respective app folder and reflect it in admin page.

However if what you're trying here is to compile every model in one admin.py. Django wont detect that file by default. Another way to do this, you can try create a new app "admin" and register every model in that folder. I never did this because admin.py separated in their own app has its own very significant purpose.